# Invalid target release when compiling Java application

Tags: java, maven-3

I get this error when I run `mvn clean package` in my IntelliJ terminal:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) on project protection: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.8 -> [Help 1]
> [ERROR]
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
> [ERROR]
> [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
> [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Is this telling me that it is trying to compile with Java 1.8 or that it expects Java 1.8 but the available version is not correct?

Comment: `release` was not available until 9; use `source` and `target`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using 1.8.And the default value for the compiler is 1.6 so you need to change the plugin  properties to:

```
<plugins>
 <plugin>    
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
 </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: Where do you see the default value of 1.6?

Comment: meven compiler plugin  has the default  value  of 1.6 you can read more about it here [link](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-java-version)